# merge cells in multiple columns base on cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to automate the merging of cells based by column for multiple columns based on the information in a specific column.

Base on the Initial image, the Stack value will determine the no. of rows to merge for Color, Stack and Size column as shown in Outcome screenshot.

I found this code below but I don't know how to adapt it to my requirement. (I am new on code and am learning)

```
Dim srw As Long, frw As Variant
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    With Intersect(.Columns(3), .UsedRange)
        srw = 0
        Do While srw < .Rows.Count
            frw = .Cells(srw + 1, 1).Value
            If Not IsError(frw) Then
                .Cells(srw + 1, 1).Resize(frw, 1).Offset(0, -1).Merge
                srw = srw + frw
            Else
                srw = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            End If
        Loop
    End With
End With
```

Initial:
[image: Initial]

Outcome:
[image: Outcome]

Comment: Merged cells are a PITA for several reasons. When possible, always prefer `CenterAcrossSelection`, which is visually similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this code

```
Sub Test()
Dim x, r As Long, c As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        For r = 2 To .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            x = .Cells(r, 3).Value
            If IsNumeric(x) And x > 1 Then
                For c = 2 To 4
                    .Cells(r, c).Resize(x).Merge
                Next c
            End If
        Next r
    End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Let's say I have multiple tables of data with the same type and format on 1 sheet and there are multiple sheets. And how can I get the macro to run automatically everytime I open the workbook.

Comment: Great! I found this:
    Private Sub Workbook_Open()
        ...
    End Sub

Comment: Yes!that it is!

Answer (score 1):

Change sheet name and range if needed and try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim Number_Of_Rows As Long
    Dim wsTest As Worksheet

    With wsTest
        LastRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 2 To LastRow
            If .Range("C" & i).Value > 1 Then
                Number_Of_Rows = .Range("C" & i).Value
                With .Range("B" & .Range("C" & i).Row & ":B" & .Range("C" & i).Row + (Number_Of_Rows - 1))
                    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                    .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
                    .MergeCells = True
                End With
                With .Range("C" & .Range("C" & i).Row & ":C" & .Range("C" & i).Row + (Number_Of_Rows - 1))
                    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                    .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
                    .MergeCells = True
                End With
                With .Range("D" & .Range("C" & i).Row & ":D" & .Range("C" & i).Row + (Number_Of_Rows - 1))
                    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                    .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
                    .MergeCells = True
                End With
            ElseIf .Range("C" & i).Value <> "" Then
                With .Range("B" & i & ":D" & i)
                    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                    .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
                End With
            End If
        Next i
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Nice! But the sample screenshot is just an abbreviated example and the code will be very lengthy if let's say I have large no. of  columns eg. >20 to merge.